# Как заполнить форму на сайте через элемент WebView?

Tags: java, android, форма, веб-сайт

Нужно программно заполнить форму на сайте и нажать кнопку Вход. Язык программирования - Java.

[image: d]

---

Да, полей там несколько, но когда я в браузере захожу на свой сайт и вручную ввожу логин и пароль а потом нажимаю на конпку "Вход", все работает и данные записываются в текстовик а когда с андроида вашим методом то нет. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой код:

```
package com.rost.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onbtnclick (View v){
        String email = "YourEmailForForm";
        String password = "YourPasswordForForm";
/*Пусть имена полей формы будут 'user_email' и 'user_password'
для почты и пароля соответственно*/
        String data = "username=" + email + "&password=" + password;

        /*Ниже выполняется в отдельном потоке*/
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://тут мой сайт/");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());
            con.connect();
            int code = con.getResponseCode();
            con.disconnect();
            Toast.makeText(this,"cool", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Ошибочка
            Toast.makeText(this,"bad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит «программно»? 1. Вообще не показывать пользователю форму и отправить нужные данные на север. 2. Показать пользователю уже заполненную форму для того, чтобы пользователь её отправил. Или что-нибудь другое?

Comment: Пользователь не должен видеть форму. Есть кнопка, она находится в нашем приложении android. По нажатию на нее на сайте заполняются два поля(email и пароль например) и после этого нажимается кнопка входа, тоже программно. Пользователь не видет всего происходящего на сайте.

Comment: Зачем тогда нужен вам этот WebView. Просто узнайте имена полей ввода и отправьте их на сервер (скорее всего, это будет POST-запрос)

Comment: Расскажите,пожалуйста, подробнее как это сделать.